# Unicode text through socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, unicode, utf-8

I am facing a tiny issue (I believe) in socket programming. When sending text from non-English languages, I get garbled results. After a lot of researching on google, I made some corrections. I changed `getBytes()` to `getBytes("UTF-8")` and tried to send some Arabic text.

When connecting sockets locally, it works fine. I see the arabic text I expected. But when testing from online, the results display strange/garbled characters.

Here is the text I tried:

"مرحبا" (this is the arab text of "hello") which displayed to me as "Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§"

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Post your server write and client read code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some Java code I had lying around that’s used for setting the stream encodings on a pair of byte streams, but you could do the same with a singleton, at least assuming you’re using TCP stream sockets not UDP datagrams.

```
    Process
    slave_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdname -opts cmdargs");

 OutputStream
 __bytes_into_his_stdin  = slave_process.getOutputStream();

 OutputStreamWriter
   chars_into_his_stdin  = new OutputStreamWriter(
                             __bytes_into_his_stdin,
         /* DO NOT OMIT! */  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()
                         );

 InputStream
 __bytes_from_his_stdout = slave_process.getInputStream();

 InputStreamReader
   chars_from_his_stdout = new InputStreamReader(
                             __bytes_from_his_stdout,
         /* DO NOT OMIT! */  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()
                         );

 InputStream
 __bytes_from_his_stderr = slave_process.getErrorStream();

 InputStreamReader
   chars_from_his_stderr = new InputStreamReader(
                             __bytes_from_his_stderr,
         /* DO NOT OMIT! */  Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()
                         );
```

Comment: yes man "InputStreamReader & OutputStreamWriter" did the work well for me... thank you for your contribution...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, you forgot to specify encoding on string creation.

```
byte[] utf8bytes = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");       // encoding
String otherString = new String(utf8bytes, "UTF-8");   // decoding
```

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just wrap the stream with the correct decoder?  Manual decoding data to or from a stream that is all in one encoding is surely the wrong approach, don’t you think?

Comment: Well @mersenne i used the same like what you said... with that above two line which u said i successfully sent unicode text to socket listener in server... and after server gets it it sends to other client listeners where i get the same annoying text..

Comment: @tchrist: What is the correct decoder then? It is good to advice architectural changes, but it requires more detailed examples and some knowledge about source code.

Comment: @Mersenne The rule-of-thumb is that streams in a single encoding should *always* have their raw bytes ***implicitly converted into characters*** by the right call to `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)` or `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, CharsetEncoder enc)`. That way you deal only in Java characters; it’s a cleaner abstraction less prone to error and to repeating yourself. Calling `getBytes` is an antipattern for those scenarios.

Comment: @tchrist: that's right, that's right. I just can't be sure that it is all about simple text data. Sources are pending. Also, if we throw away old code completely and replace it with new logic (with better logic, of course), author will never know what was wrong with his original sources.

Comment: @tchrist your suggestion "InputStreamReader & OutputStreamWriter" worked well and i got it working... thank you guys for ur suggestions...

Comment: @Spicyjazz Glad to hear it. It’s always easiest if you can let the byte-to-character translation happen implicitly that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this would be to use a Serialized object that has a String container with your arabic text inside it.

Don't write the bytes directly, instead use:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = yourSocket.getOutputStream();
oos.writeObject(yourContainer);
```

Then on the receiving end, do this:

```
if (receivedObject instanceof YourContainer) {
    // get out arabic string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still trying to solve this :

in your Socket response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8\r\n\r\n
```

Just don't forget the Content-Type with charset set to utf8
it should work with Arabic letters.