# Socket programming with OutputStreamWriter & greek charset to print

Tags: java, android, sockets, printing

Let's explain my problem first. I have post another question similar here : [PrintStream doesn't print correctly unicode characters ( UTF-16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251688/printstream-doesnt-print-correctly-unicode-characters-utf-16) but somehow I didn't manage to overcome the problem.

I want to print from android to a network printer(Xerox WC 24 PCL or EPSON XP-600).
  Let's say :

```
Socket client = new Socket(_IP, PORT);     // IP, port
```

I have the following text :

```
String[] str =  {   "-------------------------------------------------\r\n",
                " ΠΕΛΑΤΗΣ   : Γεια σου Πελάτη\r\n",
                " ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ   : 00000234242\r\n",
                " ΔΙΕΥΘΗΝΣΗ     : Περικλέους 77\r\n",
                " ΤΗΛ.      : 2310-892345\r\n",
                             "-------------------------------------------------\r\n"
            };
```

and then I call with "ISO-8859-7", "Windows-1253" ( greek characters ) the following code :

```
OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(os, Charset.forName(enc).newEncoder());

    for(int i =0; i< str.length; i++) {

        oStream.write(str[i]);



        oStream.flush();
    }

           oStream.close();
```

But the result to the printer ( in console of eclipse is ok ) I get garbages like :

```
  -------------------------------------------------
   ÅéùêåÛ   : èÛæÅéùêåÛ
   èÛæÅ     : 00000234242
   Åéùêå : ÛÅéùêåÛ
   ñ÷æÅ     : 2310-892345
  -------------------------------------------------
```

which are the extended ASCII characters found here : http://www.ascii-code.com/
Can anyone tell me how to tell the printer to print the correct format of my characters? For greek characters is "ISO-8859-7", "Windows-1253", ""Cp1253".
A solution for Arabic characters is here but it's not working at least for me : [Unicode text through socket in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384720/unicode-text-through-socket-in-java)

Also, no success with PLC ISO 8859 7. I send strings like :

```
"\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4\u03b5\u03b6\u03b7\u03b8\u03b9\u03ba\u03bb\u03bc\u03bd\u03be\u03bf\u03c0\u03c1\u03c3\u03c2\u03c4\u03c5\u03c6\u03c7\u03c8\u03c9\r\n",
```

"\033(12N\r\n",
"a b c à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý þ\r\n",

I have no luck

Comment: If you are seeing the expected output in the console, but not at the printer, my first thought would be that you need to check your printer documentation for setting the encoding or using a different driver

Comment: I think what you see is the `ISO-8859-7` characters interpreted in plain ASCII charset... Do you see this sign in the first line? `Ð`

Comment: Actually, I realize that my problem is how to make a printer driver for greeks.

Comment: I send 'raw' data to the printer and I expect printer to recognize them. I have to conform with printers protocol with greek letters

Answer (score 0):

For a PCL printer, you can send a PCL command to change the symbol set. If I read [this source](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=0&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-bpl04632-2%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#N10050) and [this source](http://www.pclviewer.com/resources/pcl_symbolset.html) correctly, and the printer in question supports it, you can make it use the ISO-8859-7 symbol set with this:

```
oStream.write("\033(12N");
```

Comment: No success. I have read PCL ISO 8859_7. I sent to printer also :

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is simple. I have to write a printer driver for the specific printer so that I can print unicode, greek, japanase or whatever characters. Only with socket there is no such a way, at least in my 'unicode' case.